# Convert datenum back to date when plotting in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I'm doing a simple plot in Matlab of windspeed vs time. I converted time using the datenum function, and able to do this plot.  However, is there a way to convert the datenum outputs back into a date format when plotting?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [datetick](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datetick.html) function. It will convert the serial date numbers to human readable date.

Comment: Not working. MATLAB seems to have some really big issues with converting from datenum to something else. Datetick is not working, datestr(some_datenum), datevec(some_datenum) are also returning completely wrong results.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure when it was added, but now you can use the `datetime` format in the `plot` command:

taken from [MATLAB docs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html#bugxq9j-9) (have a look also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41322696/plotting-data-with-time-series-in-matlab)):

```
t = 0:seconds(30):minutes(3);
y = rand(1,7);
plot(t,y,'DurationTickFormat','mm:ss')
```

will generate (something like) this:

[image: DateTime plot]