# Plotting data with time series in matlab

Tags: matlab, datetime, plot, time-series, matlab-figure

I have some data from 2007/5/1 to 2007/5/30 from 00:00 to 23:59:58. I want to plot these data according to data and time together. How can I define both date and time together? cause it has a regular date and time. For example

```
2007/5/1 00:00:00       -0.2
2007/5/1 00:00:02       -0.1
2007/5/1 00:00:04       -0.12
.
.
. 
2007/5/31 23:59:58      -0.4
```

I've been used DateTime code but I have regular time interval and I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: Is your vector of time is in `datetime` format? If so you just neet to use `plot` as usual. Try to put here an example o the wanted output and what you have got so far.

Comment: No, actually it doesn't have datetime format, but i have consecutive data in which i know that the first data is for 00:00:00 2007/5/1 with a same step in time .

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example for using a `datetime` variable. You'll need to import your data to a corresponding vector that aligns with the time vector (`t` below) so that `data(i)` is the relevant data for `t(i)`.

```
% create a datetime vector of all instances:
start = datetime('2007/5/1 00:00:00','InputFormat','uuuu/MM/dd HH:mm:ss');
step = duration(seconds(2));
fin = datetime('2007/5/31 23:59:58','InputFormat','uuuu/MM/dd HH:mm:ss');
t = start:step:fin; % a 1339200 elements vector, of all time steps
% some random data:
data = rand(numel(t),1);
% plotting samples 1 to 100:
plot(t(1:100),data(1:100))
xlim([datenum(t(1)) datenum(t(100))])
```

I use here random numbers for the example, and you won't be able to see anything for such a long vector, so I plot only a portion of it:

[image: plotDate]

Comment: I have 1440 data for each day it means that it has a higher precision than seconds... how can I define that? 
And how can I plot the time series to see its whole evolution?

Comment: 1440 samples for a day is a **lower** precision of 1min per sample, you can change: `step = duration(minutes(1))` so you get all the minutes in this period. If you want to plot all the time series just write: `plot(t,data)`