# How to plot datetime in x axis in MATLAB or Octave

Tags: matlab, date, datetime, plot, octave

In MATLAB or Octave, my data has the following format for date/time values:

12:00:34.626 AM 2/26/2017

where it is HH:MM:SS:SSS [A or P]M [M]M/DD/YYYY

I want to use it for my x-axis on my plots, and I have tried using *datetick*, *datenum*, and *datestr* and haven't been able to get any of them to work with this format.

How can I use this formatted value string to label my x-axis datapoints?

Answer (score 2):

I would use a combination of these functions, namely **datnum** followed by **datetick** after plotting.

First off your formating string need to be: 'HH:MM:SS.FFF AM mm/dd/yyyy'.

See the following if you need to change format:
https://au.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2016b/matlab/ref/datenum.html#inputarg_formatIn

Then use **datetick** to convert to nice format on plot.
https://au.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2016b/matlab/ref/datetick.html

So to a single data point= plot you might have:

```
xdatestr=['12:00:34.626 AM 2/26/2017'; '12:00:34.626 PM 2/26/2017']
xdatenum=datenum(xdatestr,'HH:MM:SS.FFF AM mm/dd/yyyy')
plot(xdatenum,[0 1])
datetick(gca)
```

Also note **datetime**, is whole seperate way of doing it, and uses a different format string convention.
http://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datetime.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following format:

```
d = datetime('12:00:34.626 AM 2/26/2017','InputFormat','hh:mm:ss.SSS a M/dd/yyyy')
```

result:

```
d = 
   26-Feb-2017 00:00:34
```

and if you want to see also the fractions of a second:

```
>> d.Second
ans =
       34.626
```

For multiple dates strings, stored in a cell array, just replace the string `'12:00:34.626 AM 2/26/2017'` above with the cell array.

Then you just write `plot(d,y)` (where `y` is your data) and you get the x-axis in a time format. You can further customize this format by using the `DatetimeTickFormat` property:

```
plot(d,1,'DatetimeTickFormat','hh:mm:ss.SSS a M/dd/yyyy')
```

And you will get:

[image: DatetimeTickFormat]

see also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41322696/plotting-data-with-time-series-in-matlab) and [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html#input_argument_namevalue_DatetimeTickFormat).

Comment: datetime isn't defined in Octave

Comment: I don't use Octave. You wrote MATLAB _or_ Octave.

Answer (score 1):

Another example is this.

```
date={'12:00:34.600 AM 2/26/2017','12:00:34.700 AM 2/26/2017','12:00:34.800 AM 2/26/2017','12:00:34.900 AM 2/26/2017'};
timeFormat='HH:MM:SS.FFF AM mm/dd/yyyy';
xdatenum=datenum(date,timeFormat);
data=0:3;
plot(xdatenum,data)
datetick('x',timeFormat,'keepticks')
view([-20,90])
```

I tilted the plot a little to avoid overlap of x ticks.

You can control the number of ticks by using tick properties.

```
date={'12:00:34.600 AM 2/26/2017','12:00:34.700 AM 2/26/2017','12:00:34.800 AM 2/26/2017','12:00:34.900 AM 2/26/2017'};
timeFormat='HH:MM:SS.FFF AM mm/dd/yyyy';
xdatenum=datenum(date,timeFormat);
data=0:3;
plot(xdatenum,data)
datetick('x',timeFormat,'keepticks')
set(gca,'XTick',[min(xdatenum) max(xdatenum)])
set(gca,'XTickLabel',[date(1),date(end)])
```

Here, I made just two ticks with minimum date and maximum date.