# How to plot seconds interval on x axis in Octave

Tags: plot, octave

I had a look on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42498191/how-to-plot-datetime-in-x-axis-in-matlab-or-octave) question which works well.

But I am not able to reduce the interval to seconds by modifying the first line of the answer from

```
xdatestr=['12:00:34.626 AM 2/26/2017'; '12:00:34.626 PM 2/26/2017']
```

to

```
xdatestr=['12:00:34.626 AM 2/26/2017'; '12:00:35.626 AM 2/26/2017']
```

How can I do this?

Complete sample:

```
xdatestr=['12:00:34.626 AM 2/26/2017'; '12:00:35.626 AM 2/26/2017']
xdatenum=datenum(xdatestr,'HH:MM:SS.FFF AM mm/dd/yyyy')
plot(xdatenum,[0 1])
datetick(gca)
```

My goal is to plot data in seconds (or minutes) interval.

Comment: Found the answer. Just run into the problem described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65320481/plot-with-dates-goes-wrong)